# Implementing cron for Laravel is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5 installed via composer on Ubuntu server.

My cron command looks like:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/domain/public_html && php artisan schedule:run
```

And i get email from server with: "Could not open input file: artisan".

If i go to laravel directory, i can successfully run: `php artisan command:command`.

Cron is run as root.

If i remove "&&" from command, then nothing happens.

Any ideas, why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this section in the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#introduction

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/domain/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/yourprojectname/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For more details please follow this [link](https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#introduction or previous laravel version should tell you ... and this is my setting in cron * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/domain/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in cron command.

This command works:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/domain/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```